# how to get value from json file using jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui

This is my jquery code

$('.typeahead', this).autocomplete({

```
        source: function(request, response) {

            $.ajax({

                url: 'includes/stations.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: request,
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item, i) {

                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.code
                            }
                    }));
                },



            });
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
```

My Json File is 
[
  {
    "code": "9BP3",
    "name": "9Bp No3"
  },
  {
    "code": "AA",
    "name": "Ataria"
  },{
    "code": "BILA",
    "name": "Bheslana"
  },
  {
    "code": "BILD",
    "name": "Bildi"
  },{
    "code": "HRI",
    "name": "Hardoi"
  },
  {
    "code": "HRM",
    "name": "Hadmadiya"
  }
]

When i typing any three letter its returns whole json file values

Answer (score 0):

**q: request.term** this is the string for filter returned values from stations.json. You must pass variable like this to filter results. stations.json must be dynamically generated file like php with json header. q is $_GET parameter and must be parsed. Try to change the code like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "includes/stations.json",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    q: request.term // here is the string for filter returned values from stations.json. You must pass variable like this to filter results. stations.json must be dynamically generated file like php with json header. q is $_GET parameter and must be parsed.
  },
  success: function(data) {
    response(
        $.map(data, function(item, i) {
            return {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.code
            }
        })
    );
}
});
},
minLength: 3,
```